# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tick_params' when plotting histograms in 'for' loop but not sure why

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, histogram

I have the following code.

I am trying to loop through columns of a dataframe **(newerdf)** and plot a **histogram** for each one.

I am then saving each plot as a .png file on my desktop.

However, the following code gives me the error: **'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tick_params'.**

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

```
listedvariables = ['distance','age']
for i in range(0,len(listedvariables)): 
    x = newerdf[[listedvariables[i]]].hist(figsize=(50,50))
    x.tick_params(axis='x',labelsize=60) 
    x.tick_params(axis='y',labelsize=60)
    x.set_xlabel(var,fontsize=70,labelpad=30,weight='bold')
    x.set_ylabel('Number of participants',fontsize=70,labelpad=30,weight='bold') 
    x.set_title(var,fontsize=70,pad=30,weight='bold') 
    dir_name = "/Users/macbook/Desktop/UCL PhD Work/"
    plt.rcParams["savefig.directory"] = os.chdir(os.path.dirname(dir_name))
    plt.savefig(var+' '+'histogram')
    plt.show()
```

The first 10 rows of newerdf['age'] look like this:

```
0     21.0
1     24.0
2     47.0
3     32.0
5     29.0
6     29.0
7     22.0
8     23.0
9     32.0
10    22.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataFrame.hist()` function returns, according to its [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html), a matplotlib axes or a numpy array of them, if your dataframe has more then one column.

> This function calls matplotlib.pyplot.hist(), on each series in the DataFrame, resulting in one histogram per column.

Thus in this line,

```py
x = newerdf[[listedvariables[i]]].hist(figsize=(50,50))
```

`x` is set to a numpy array, and numpy arrays have no attribute `tick_params`.

to fix this, loop over the values in x as:

```py
for i in range(0,len(listedvariables)): 
    x = newerdf[[listedvariables[i]]].hist(figsize=(50,50))
    for hist in x:
         # remainder of your code
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Sadly I still get: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tick_params' :(

Comment: I have now managed to solve it - thank you! :)

Comment: If you solved it, than it is best to post the solution as an answer and accept it so that other people that need the answer to your specific problem know how to solve it

Comment: Have done so :) see above

Answer (score 0):

The following code works.

I added '.plot' between the df 'newer[df]' and 'hist'.

```
listedvariables = ['distance','age']
for i in range(0,len(listedvariables)): 
    x = newerdf[[listedvariables[i]]].plot.hist(figsize=(50,50))
    x.tick_params(axis='x',labelsize=60) 
    x.tick_params(axis='y',labelsize=60)
    x.set_xlabel(listedvariables[i],fontsize=70,labelpad=30,weight='bold')
    x.set_ylabel('Number of participants',fontsize=70,labelpad=30,weight='bold') 
    x.set_title(listedvariables[i],fontsize=70,pad=30,weight='bold') 
    dir_name = "/Users/macbook/Desktop/UCL PhD Work/"
    plt.rcParams["savefig.directory"] = os.chdir(os.path.dirname(dir_name))
    plt.savefig(listedvariables[i]+' '+'histogram')
    plt.show()
```